# Convert function from ActionScript to Javascript

Tags: javascript, actionscript, get, arrays

I receive a get request from server, but is encrypted with a simple algorithm in Python, so I have this Method in ActionScript for decrypt this :

`public static function Decrypt (encrypted : String) : String

{

   var resultArray : ByteArray = new ByteArray();

   for (var i:int = 0; i < encrypted.length; i++){

      resultArray.writeByte(encrypted.charCodeAt(i) ^ 0x34);

   }
   var resultString : String =  resultArray.toString();

   return resultString;

}`

Now, I need to implement this function in Javascript, but there is no `ByteArray` class  in JS, any idea of how i can do this? Code and librarys are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 function Decrypt(encrypted) {
    var resultString = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < encrypted.length; i++) {
        resultString += String.fromCharCode(encrypted.charCodeAt(i) ^ 0x34);
    } 
    return resultString;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, the `fromCharCode` function is what i was looking for :D

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
function Decrypt(encrypted) {
    var resultString = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < encrypted.length; i++) {
        resultString += (encrypted[i] ^ 0x34);
    } 
    return resultString
}
```

Comment: why the post was downvoted? If you don't tell I can't improve the answer.

Comment: the typo was corrected. Don't work how? Is there is any error message? Can't test without some sample data...

Comment: Missed `String.fromCharCode` function, that's the detail, check @Diode answer

Answer (score 0):

Just replace it with a normal JS array ( `[]` ) and change `resultArray.writeByte` to `resultArray.push`.  Also make `resultArray.toString()` into `resultArray.join('')`.  All the rest of the code should work as is (assuming you drop things like `public static`, `: String`, `:int`, etc that aren't valid in JS)

Comment: What about the `writeByte` function? Should I use push instead?